# Internal page link does not W3C validate

Tags: html

I have a link to a spot further down the same page as so:

```
<a href="#info" name="info" title="Click to view info">Click to view info</a>
```

... later...

```
<h3 id="info">Here is some info</h3>
<p>...</p>
```

So it works fine, but when I run it through the W3C validator it says that the name attribute is obsolete. How else can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the `name` attribute.

The `id` attribute is the replacement, which you are using already (and on the correct element!), and you don't want the anchor to link to itself anyway.

Comment: So do I need to put the ID on the link itself, or just keep the id on the element that's hyperlinked to? (ie. the h3)

Comment: Just keep the id on the element you are linking to.